# referencing dictionary in another function

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out where i went wrong.

```
def aaa():
    A123_dict = {'01':'abc', '02':'def', '03':'ghi'}
    return A123_dict
    # A123_dict=aaa()


# aaa()

def zzz():
    Z456_dict = {'01':[a, b, c], '02':[d, e, f], '03':[g, h, i]}
    return Z456_dict
    # Z456_dict=zzz()


# zzz()


def NewFunction(A123_dict, Z456_dict):
    print(A123_dict.items())
    print(Z456_dict.items())


NewFunction(A123_dict, Z456_dict)
```

Why am i getting this error here?
line 23, in < module >
NewFunction(A123_dict, Z456_dict)
NameError: name 'A123_dict' is not defined

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `return` means? In your own words, when you write `NewFunction(A123_dict, Z456_dict)`, where do you expect the value for `A123_dict` to come from? Why? How? In your own words, why is your commented-out code commented out? What exactly is going on there?

Comment: You should read a tutorial and make sure you understand how calling functions works. You should also make sure you understand the terminology you are using; "calling dictionary in another function" *makes no sense*. The thing that you "call" is *the function*, not the dictionary.

Comment: I'm pretty new to python and still trying to figure dictionary out. WhatI'm hoping to do is at the end of the day reference the key of each dict and come out with a result where i can do a ```{'abc':[a,b,c], 'def':[d,e,f], 'ghi':[g,h,i]}```

Comment: The problem isn't anything to do with dictionaries. The problem is completely to do with your (mis)understanding of how functions work. Please review that. For example, you can try putting `python using functions tutorial` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+using+functions+tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

The variables inside your functions **aaa** and **zzz** get created inside the **local scope of the functions**, and are therefore **not accessible outside of those**. Thus the two variables are not defined in the **global scope** and you get an error.

when you want to retrieve the dictionaries of those 2 functions then you should use a **return statement**.

Comment: Now i'm returning the dict in local scope of the 1st 2 functions. how do i make them global?

Comment: @mc.python   Simply assign their **return value** to a variable in the **global scope**

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `NameError: name 'A123_dict' is not defined` because the variable `A123_dict` is defined inside a function and is not accessible where you're using it in the outer scope.

You need to call functions `aaa` and `zzz` and save the values returned before you pass them to `NewFunction`.

```
A123_dict = aaa()
Z456_dict = zzz()
NewFunction(A123_dict, Z456_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as in the previous message, it seems that is because the functions are not in scope, I took a quick look at your code, I made each of the functions to return the items, so you can simply call them.

```
def aaa():
    A123_dict = {'01':'abc', '02':'def', '03':'ghi'}
    return A123_dict.items()
    # A123_dict=aaa() 
    # aaa()
    
def zzz():
    Z456_dict = {'01':["a", "b", "c"], '02':["d", "e", "f"], '03':["g", "h", "i"]}
    return Z456_dict.items()
    # Z456_dict=zzz()
    
    
# zzz()


def NewFunction():
    print(aaa())
    print(zzz())

NewFunction()
```

This prints the items of each dictionary just fine.

Comment: Thanks David, the new function works.<br>How do i use the A123_dict and Z456_dict in the NewFunction?<br>Now when i print aaa() and zzz(), it shows  ```dict_items([('01', 'abc'), ('02', 'def'), ('03', 'ghi')])
dict_items([('01', ['a', 'b', 'c']), ('02', ['d', 'e', 'f']), ('03', ['g', 'h', 'i'])])```Am i able to use the keys and values in aaa() and zzz() ?

Answer (score 0):

The two dictionaries that you are using are not defined outside of a function. To do that, you will need to do something like this:

```
dict_1 = aaa()
dict_2 = zzz()

NewFunction(dict_1, dict_2)
```

Comment: It takes a good effort to help the community which is totally agreed upon. Great! However, your answer should be produced in a rightful manner such that it always acts as a rightful guide to rely on. Make sure the specify the functions in lowercase. This is rightful accordance as defined in PEP.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.